# Invalid redirect_uri in Duende Identity server 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, duende-identity-server

I am trying to use Identity Server 6 for authentication and authorization in my MVC project in .NET 6. I am also using Identity Server to restrict access to my APIs which talks to my MVC project.
When I start my solution, I start all 3 projects under the solutions - Web MVC project with swagger UI, Product API and Identity server API project. When I try to login to my MVC api project , in the console running in the background , I am getting the following error -

```
Duende.IdentityServer.Events.DefaultEventService[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "mango",
        "Endpoint": "Authorize",
        "Scopes": "",
        "Error": "invalid_request",
        "ErrorDescription": "Invalid redirect_uri",
        "Category": "Token",
        "Name": "Token Issued Failure",
        "EventType": "Failure",
        "Id": 2001,
        "ActivityId": "0HMH1EO8KTSBE:00000003",
        "TimeStamp": "2022-04-18T20:00:33Z",
        "ProcessId": 41032,
        "LocalIpAddress": "::1:7270",
        "RemoteIpAddress": "::1"
      }
```

Here is the code for HomeController of my MVC project -

```
using Mango.Web.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Mango.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
        {

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code for my Program.cs for my MVC project -

```
using Mango.Web;
using Mango.Web.Services;
using Mango.Web.Services.IServices;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IProductService, ProductService>();
Constants.ProductAPIBase = builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:ProductAPI"];
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();


//setup main proj to use Identityserver , openID connect
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
                .AddCookie("Cookies", c => c.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = builder.Configuration["ServiceUrls:IdentityAPI"];
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.ClientId = "mango";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role", "role");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("sub", "sub", "sub");
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
                    options.Scope.Add("mango");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json file for MVC project -

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ServiceUrls": {
    "ProductAPI": "https://localhost:7174",
    "IdentityAPI": "https://localhost:7270"
  }
}
```

Static class SD.vc in my Identity API project -

```
namespace Mango.Services.Identity
{
    using Duende.IdentityServer;
    using Duende.IdentityServer.Models;
    public static class SD
    {
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
        public const string Customer = "Customer";

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
          new List<IdentityResource>
          {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
          };

        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new List<ApiScope> {
                new ApiScope("mango", "Mango Server"),
                new ApiScope(name: "read",   displayName: "Read your data."),
                new ApiScope(name: "write",  displayName: "Write your data."),
                new ApiScope(name: "delete", displayName: "Delete your data.")
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId="client",
                    ClientSecrets= { new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes={ "read", "write","profile"}
                },
                //creating custom client for our mango app
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId="mango",
                    ClientSecrets= { new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    // for openid connect , we add signin-oidc
                    //44360 , 7182
                    RedirectUris={ "https://localhost:44360/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:7182/signin-oidc" },
                    //url to redirect after logout - main app
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris={"https://localhost:44360/signout-callback-oidc" },
                    AllowedScopes=new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        "mango"
                    }
                },
            };
    }
}
```

Program.cs file for Identity API project -

```
using Mango.Services.Identity;
using Mango.Services.Identity.DbContext;
using Mango.Services.Identity.Initializer;
using Mango.Services.Identity.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// configure identityserver to use our App user class
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

//adding identityserver
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
})
    //using our resources and apiscopes
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(SD.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(SD.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(SD.Clients)
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDbInitializer, DbInitializer>();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

//adding identity server to the pipeline
app.UseIdentityServer();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbInitializer>().Initialize();
    
}
//app.Services.GetService<IDbInitializer>().Initialize();


app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json  for Identity API -----

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=Local;Database=MangoIdentityServer;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

I am not sure here what is exactly causing this issue. I have verified my IdentityServer is running on https://localhost:7270/.

Comment: See your log, it shows two errors. Can you share your code about  Identity server API project's program and appsettings.json for other two projects?

Comment: To add support for OpenID Connect authentication to the MVC application, you first need to add the nuget package containing the OpenID Connect handler to your project. like : ‘using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; ’， 
 'JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;’ In your MVC program I don't see it.

Comment: @QingGuo I have added the files that you have asked for. I have included the package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt in the project, but yes I have not started creating any tokens yet. Where should I add the code to generate tokens and set MapInboundClaims to false ? Do you have any reference sample code for .NET 6 ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add mvc project's url in redirect_uri list of a client in identity server.

Lets say your mvc project url is "https://localhost:9999", add this address in redirect_uri list.

e.g in you identity api, you have a client mango;

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId="mango",
                ClientSecrets= { new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                // for openid connect , we add signin-oidc
                //44360 , 7182
                RedirectUris={ "https://localhost:44360/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:7182/signin-oidc" },
                //url to redirect after logout - main app
                PostLogoutRedirectUris={"https://localhost:44360/signout-callback-oidc" },
                AllowedScopes=new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    "mango"
                }
            },
```

Change this line

```
RedirectUris={ "https://localhost:44360/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:7182/signin-oidc" },
```

to

```
RedirectUris={ "https://localhost:999/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:44360/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:7182/signin-oidc" },
```

Added MVC project URL in redirect_uri list.

Your MVC project is sending default value for redirect_uri to identity sever.